# Горизонтальная пагинация

Tags: java, android, pagination

Хочу использовать class HorizontalPager, взятый отсюда https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager/tree/master/src/com/github/ysamlan/horizontalpager

Имеются следующие данные:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            colors[0] = Color.parseColor("#559966CC");
            colors[1] = Color.parseColor("#55336699");

            LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
            linLayout.removeAllViews();

            LayoutInflater ltInflater = getLayoutInflater();

            for (int i = 0; i < subjects.size(); i++) {
                View item = ltInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, linLayout, false);
                TextView author = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.author);
                author.setText(authors.get(i));
                TextView subject = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.subject);
                subject.setText(subjects.get(i));
                TextView date = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.date);
                date.setText(dates.get(i));
                item.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                item.setBackgroundColor(colors[i % 2]);
                linLayout.addView(item);
            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Как сделать, чтобы данные накладывались на первую страницу? Вот, код вызова пагинации:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the view switcher
    HorizontalPager realViewSwitcher = new HorizontalPager(getApplicationContext());

    // Add some views to it
    final int[] backgroundColors =
            { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
        textView.setTextSize(100);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[i]);
        realViewSwitcher.addView(textView);
    }

    // set as content view
    setContentView(realViewSwitcher);

    realViewSwitcher.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);
}
```

Comment: а чем вам `ViewPager` из SDK не угодил? Даже сам автор библиотеки рекомендует использовать его.

Comment: Допустим у меня есть в layout LinearLayout, как мне отловить внутри него с помощью, того же ViewPager, swipe жесты влево и вправо и вывести сообщение в консоль? На данном этапе для меня это сложно(

Comment: Класс `ViewPager` имеет колбэк-интерфейс [`OnPageChangeListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), который срабатывает, когда свайпятся страницы.Интерфейс позволяет реализовать метод  `onPageScrolled()`. Перепишите свой вопрос так, чтобы из него было понятно, что у вас на самом деле за проблема.

Comment: Нашел готовое решении тут http://darkraha.com/rus/mobile/android/gui/layouts/scrollviewext.php , спасибо за помощь!